# How to get the location id for a specific hotel registered in TripAdvisor

Tags: rest

I want to get the rating and reviews of a specific hotel for that I am using the TripAdvisor API.

I got this link:

```
api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/location/**8957**5?key=<YOUR KEY HERE>
```

But how can I get the unique ID for a hotel (location id)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unique id is the one after "location/**unique_id**", and how to get the id of the hotel well that depends on the way your application works.

1. You can navigate through the TripAdvisor site to find the hotel you want, and the id is part of the URL **after the D**:

   > http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g297484-d616578-Reviews-Irotama_Resort-Santa_Marta_Santa_Marta_District_Magdalena_Department.html -> The id is **616578**
2. Or you can perform a search by latitude and longitude with this url: `http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/map/42.33141,-71.099396?key=<YOUR_KEY>`
   and select the place you want in the results with the key **"location_id"**.

See [TripAdvisor Documentation](https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/mapping-individual-properties/) for more details.

Comment: now tried to integrate it in my java code by::                        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); Address_Obj obj = restTemplate.getForObject(SERVER_URI, Address_Obj.class);           but getting RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.sucl.tripAdvisor.Address_Obj]

Comment: I think option 1 is incorrect. It should be **616578** in the example above, which is the number part after **d** in the url

Comment: The answer has been edited to reflect the current TripAdvisor documentation.

Comment: how can i found the key?